# Visual Studio Code Python IntelliSense database out-of-sync after switching git branch?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In Visual Studio Code, I created and switched to a new Git branch by clicking on the branch indicator in the bottom-left of the screen and selecting "+ Create new branch...". This is the equivalent for "git branch foo" + "git checkout foo".

Then, I made some code changes in my Python classed in that new branch foo (for example: I removed some member functions of a class). To be clear, these changes are only present on my newly created branch foo which is also the active branch. These changes are not present on the main branch.

However, it appears that the IntelliSense database gets out-of-sync and still contains information from the main branch, which is not the active branch at this point in time. For example, IntelliSense will suggest possible auto-completions for class member functions that no longer exist in my active branch foo.

I am doing something wrong?

Is there a work-around (e.g. a way of resetting the IntelliSense database for Python)?

Details:

Python Extension: Microsoft ms-python.python version 2020.1.57204 (6 January 2020)

Visual Studio Code: version 1.41.1

Python version 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the two IntelliSense engines (Jedi or the Microsoft Python Language Server) to see if either solves your problem. If neither does then you can open a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.